# Subscribe to view controller property without nested subscribe loop

Tags: swift, rx-swift

How can I make this subscribe loop not be nested? I can't seem to figure out how you would go about doing this because I push the view controller in the main subscribe loop, and not just set a value.

```
button.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
    let viewController = MyViewController()
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController)
    viewController.myPublishRelay.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { value in
        // do something with value

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You desire two different side effects, so it makes sense to have two subscription. To prevent from nesting, you could do something in the lines of this:

```
let viewControllerToPresent = button.rx.tap.map { _ in
  return MyViewController()
}.share()

viewControllerToPresent.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] viewController in
  self.view.pushViewController(viewController)
}.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

viewControllerToPresent.flatMapLatest { viewController in
  viewController.myPublishRelay.asObservable()
}.subscribe(onNext: { value in
  // do something with value
}.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

The call to `share` is important here, otherwise the mapping after `rx.tap` would occur twice, making us subscribe to the publish relay of a view controller that is **not** the one we presented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sample()` or `.combineLatest()`, depending on how does your `publishRelay` update.

For example, `Observable.combineLatest(myPublishRelay, button.rx.tap) { $0 }.subscribe(onNext: { value ...`

See http://rxmarbles.com for reference on operators.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see a nested subscribe I think of `flatMap`.  Something like this should work:

```
button.rx.tap
    .flatMap { _ in
        let viewController = MyViewController()
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController)

        return viewController.myPublishRelay.asObservable()
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { value in
        // do something with value
    })
```